# OSX: Check if the default interface is physical or virtual

Tags: macos, networking, network-programming

Is there way on OSX to see if the default interface is an actual physical interface or if it is a virtual interface like when it is connected to a VPN?

Essentially, I am trying to figure out an interface property that can tell if the default interface is virtual or physical. We can read interface properties from `scutil` system configuration utility framework.

Comment: Possibly check which interface is being used when using `route` on your OS X instance to access some adress; is this what you would describe as the "default interface" for that instance? `route get google.com | grep interface`: e.g. `en0` and `en1` would correspond to physical interfaces (e.g. ethernet/airport), whereas e.g. `vmnet1` corresponds to a VMware virtual interface. This would need to you to, however, create a map as to which interface properties to map to physical/virtual.

Comment: How do you define "physical interface"? For example... is an ethernet interface connected through USB considered a "physical interface"? (one could argue that USB is physical, but the network connection is not). Going further: is a network interface connected through Bluetooth (which is how some smartphones present themselves) a "physical interface"?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are defining a virtual interface as a VPN connection, OK. However the concept of `default interface` depends on the specific address you are trying to communicate to, meaning the default interface may be different when communicating to google.com or abc.com or yourcompany.com

---

In the Mac OS X terminal you can run the `route` command against ***something meaningful***, for this example i will use `abc.com`:

```
route get abc.com | grep interface
```

For me, using wifi it reports:

```
  interface: en0
```

Then when connected to VPN over wifi it reports:

```
  interface: ppp0
```

Note that in this test I was using the VPN option 'send all traffic over vpn connection' but when i turn this off it reports `interface: en0` because abc.com is not defined as a remote network for my VPN. This is why it is important to use a ***meaningful address*** for this test.